# Can gpu use swap space when its ram is full?

Tags: memory-management, opencl, gpgpu

I'm doing some gpu calculation using OpenCL where I need to create a buffer with size about 5 GB. My laptop has an integrated gpu with 1.5 GB ram size. I tried to run the code and it gave the wrong result. So I guess it's because the ram of gpu is full. My question is that whether there is some "swap space"(or virtual memory) that gpu can utilize when its ram is full? I know that cpu has this mechanism. But I'm not sure for gpu.

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot (at least on most GPUs). Because the GPU uses its own memory (the RAM on your graphics card) in general.

Also [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) code in your kernels don't do any `malloc` (inside the kernel). You'll use [clCreateBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)

Comment: I believe that `clCreateBuffer` is limited to CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, which is somewhat less than the GPU memory size.  Perhaps that is his problem?

Comment: @Clifford I just checked CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE of my gpu. Interestingly, it returns 4 GB, which is the size of the ram of my laptop. I have an integrated Intel Iris graphics card. The operating system says it only has 1.5 GB video ram. So it seems that the gpu can utilize the total ram.

Comment: @andy90 : If the host is 32 bit, addressing >4Gb even with virtual memory will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the GPU and whether it had an MMU and DMA access to the host memory.

A GPU with an MMU can *virtualize* GPU and host memory, so that it can appear as a single address space, with the physical host memory accesses handled by DMA transfer.  I would imagine that if your GPU had that capability that would already be done; in which case you problem is most probably elsewhere.

Comment: IMHO, most real GPUs (in particular those on external NVIDIA or AMD/ATI graphics cards) don't have MMU. The APU processors from AMD are an exception.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : I am no expert; I did a little research. [This](http://traxnet.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/understanding-modern-gpus-2/) suggests that it is technically possible, and [this](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2116/2) from 2006 suggests that it has been done.